# Recorded Audio Can't be saved in /storage/emulated/0/AudioRecorder (sometimes saved file appear, sometimes not appear)

Tags: android, storage, android-mediarecorder

I want to save my recorded audio at /storage/emulated/0/AudioRecorder, This is my code :

```
private String getFilename() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/AudioRecorder");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        createdDate = DateTools.getDate(System.currentTimeMillis(),"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        nameFile = createdDate + ".mp4";

        pathFile = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + nameFile);
        return pathFile;
    }

private void startRecording() {
        if(RadioManager.getInstance().isPlaying()){
            RadioManager.getInstance().stopPlayer();
        }
        Toast.makeText(VoiceNoteActivity.this, "Mulai Rekam", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
        recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
        recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
            isRecord = true;
            countDown.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        if (null != recorder) {
            countDown.cancel();

            timer = 0;
            seekbar.setProgress(timer);
            try{
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.reset();
                recorder.release();
                recorder = null;
            }catch(RuntimeException stopException){
                //handle cleanup here
                Log.e("Voice Note Activity ","Voice Recording Error : " +stopException.getMessage());
            }

            isRecord = false;
            time.setText("00:00");
            enableButtons(false);
        }
    }
```

The file sometimes appear in /storage/emulated/0/AudioRecorder, but sometimes not appear (more often to not appear). Anybody can help ?

Comment: can u give some idea for  how to fix it now i have face the same problem @Redturbo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by adding this code :

```
File file = new File(getFilename());
        if (!file.exists()){
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

So, when the file is exist, it doesn't need to create that file again, but when saved file not exist, it needs to create the file.

Answer (score 0):

Hem.. I got same problem but with picture not voice. In my case the picture didn't appear because I haven't throw it to gallery. Based on the tutorial on android developer website is it the code for throw picture to gallery:

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
    File f = new File(fileUri.getPath());
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

may be you can use it to voice file. but I haven't try to voice file.

Comment: thanks @mas_bejo, I got clue from :  File f = new File(fileUri.getPath()); but the problem is to create file when doesn't exist, your answer has given me a clue..

Comment: can u give some idea to how to fix it now i have face the same problem @Redturbo